# slanted design via html css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

How can i achieve http://jdstiles.com/java/angledtext2.html this kind of angle(slant) using html , css and javascript. In design we have tabular structrer and by clicking on a tab the area beneath should refresh without reloading page (some thing like jquery or ajax).

Comment: Why don't you use the one you linked to?
...I think that is horrendous by the way.

Comment: I don't think he wants to do that to text, which is why I'm reserving judgment... @Nehal: Please tell me you don't want to use it for text...

Comment: Ah, legibility; **so** nineties...

Comment: "With version4+ browsers", you mean IE and Netscape Navigator? haha

Comment: Cut Uncle Jim some slant guys... :/

Answer (score 0):

The way it looks like they're doing it is by using a trigonometric function to draw out text as lines. It's vector-based, so they create a rise/run, split the word up into characters, then loop over the function, adding a span to each character, and positioning it in kind.

It's not entirely clear how you want to use it, but what you would have to do is break down your form into its smallest elements in someway, and then apply style to each element, using the basis of the trigonometric function for calculating the position of each element in a loop.

Without knowing what exactly you want to make though, it's pointless to show you what it might look like in code. The site you linked to is probably the best example of the process, even if not exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of options:

- use [this jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/2d-transform).
- use the one you linked to.
- render the text into canvas-- there are lots of examples of how to do this floating around the web. You'll need a non-canvas solution such as excanvas.js
- use one of the newer browser-specific properties manually

Using the plugin may get you going the fastest, and it will rotate the letters around.